# Smooth scrolling with two listviews inside of a scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

By product design, I am required to have two listviews inside of a scrollview. I am using reyclerviews in place of the listviews. The scrolling experience is very laggy as you might imagine. I was able to resolve the lag issue by setting NestedScrollingEnabled(false) for both of my recyclerviews.

```
rv1.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
rv2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

The conflict I am running into is that NestedScrolling is a feature for API 21+. What is the equivalent code for earlier API versions?

I have tried the following, but the list items are not clickable. The scrolling is very smooth though.

```
rv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return true;
   }
});

rv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      return true;
   }
});
```

I tried to tweak the code so that my items could be clickable, so I updated the code to the following, however, now the smooth scrolling is gone but my items are clickable.

```
rv1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      switch (action) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // disallow scrollview to intercept touch events
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // allow scrollview to intercept touch events
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

      v.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true;
   }
});


rv2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      switch (action) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // disallow scrollview to intercept touch events
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // allow scrollview to intercept touch events
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

      v.onTouchEvent(event);
      return true;
   }
});
```

I think that it could be the way my xml is structured, the parent is actually the LinearLayout wrapper and not the scrollView, although this is just my theory. I have posted how the xml is structured below.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            ....
            ....

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollingCache="false"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. The reason why listviews inside of scrollviews are so slow and laggy is mainly due to the multiple scrolling enabled within each respective view. If you can eliminate scrolling for either the listview or the scrollview everything will work smoother (not to be confused with the smoothest. It's not optimizing). So here is what I did.

I added a condition that utilized nested scrolling attribute for API 21, and in the else condition I explicitly set scrolling to be disabled in a CustomRecyclerView class.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // disable nested scrolling
        rvAirportNearest.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        rvAirportServiced.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    } else {
        // disable scrolling
        rvAirportNearest.setScrollingEnabled(false);
        rvAirportServiced.setScrollingEnabled(false);
    }
```

Here is my custom recycler view class

```
public class CustomScrollableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private boolean isScrollable = true; // by default recycler view is scrollable

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomScrollableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public CustomScrollableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public CustomScrollableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public int computeVerticalScrollRange() {
        if (isScrollable()) {
            return super.computeVerticalScrollRange();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if(isScrollable()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Method is used to set scrolling enabled
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        isScrollable = enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Method is used to check if scrolling is enabled
     * @return true if scrolling is possible, otherwise false
     */
    public boolean isScrollable() {
        return isScrollable;
    }

}
```

Hopefully this will help others facing the same issue.